# error in android code,unable to send data to mysql

Tags: php, android

I am trying to send some data to php code which can store it in table.I have tested php code it executes correctly and data in the database is stored correctly, but when called by android code there occurs exception following is the code:

//leaveapp.java

```
package com.example.eleave;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;

import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;

//import com.example.datepicker.R;

public class LeaveApp extends Activity {
     private TextView Output1,Output2,tv7,tv8;
     EditText e1;
     String date1,date2;
     String type;

        private Button changeDate1,changeDate2,btn1;
        int flag1=0,flag2=0;
        private int year;
        private int month;
        private int day;
        private Spinner spinner2;
        static final int DATE_PICKER_ID1 = 1111; 
        static final int DATE_PICKER_ID2 = 1110;
        RadioGroup rg2;
            @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.leaveapp);
            Bundle b1=getIntent().getExtras();
          final String username= b1.getString("username");
            Output1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            Output2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
            changeDate1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            changeDate2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
           spinner2=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            tv7=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
            tv8=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
            btn1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            e1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
          addItemsOnSpinner2();
            rg2=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup2);
            rg2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    switch(arg1)
                    {
                    case R.id.radioButton5:
                        flag1=1;
                        flag2=0;
                        type="0";
                        break;
                    case R.id.radioButton6:
                        flag2=1;
                        flag1=0;
                        type="1";
                        break;
                    }
                }
                });
          final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
              year=2014;
            month=c.MONTH+1;
            day=c.DAY_OF_MONTH;
                 // Button listener to show date picker dialog
              changeDate1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                            // On button click show datepicker dialog 
                    showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID1);
               }
             });
            changeDate2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                                // On button click show datepicker dialog 
                    showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ID2);
               }
            });
         btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(e1.getText().length()==0 || (flag1==0 && flag2==0)||tv7.getText().length()==0||tv8.getText().length()==0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please Enter all the fields!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else if(flag1==1)
                {

                    String sem= spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String reason=e1.getText().toString();
                    String from=date1;
                    String to=date2;
                     AsyncTask<String,Void,String> t1=new LeaveTask(LeaveApp.this).execute(username,sem,reason,from,to);
                    try{
                        String result=t1.get();
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {

                    }
                     Intent i1=new Intent(LeaveApp.this,TestSelect.class);
                    i1.putExtra("data1", spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    startActivity(i1);
                }
               else if(flag2==1)
                {
                                   finish();
                }

                }
            });
       }


        public void addItemsOnSpinner2() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            spinner2=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
            List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            list2.add("I");
            list2.add("II");
            list2.add("III");
            list2.add("IV");
            list2.add("V");
            list2.add("VI");
            list2.add("VII");
            list2.add("VIII");

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list2);
            dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
            case DATE_PICKER_ID1:


                // set date picker for current date 

                return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener1, year, month,day);


           case DATE_PICKER_ID2:


                // set date picker for current date 

                return new DatePickerDialog(this, pickerListener2, year, month,day);


            }
            return null;
        }

        private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener1 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                    int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

                year  = selectedYear;
                month = selectedMonth;
                day   = selectedDay;

                 date1=""+day+"-"+month+"-"+year+" ";
                Output1.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day).append("-").append(month + 1)
                        .append("-").append(year).append(" "));


               }
            };
            private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener pickerListener2 = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                        int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {

                    year  = selectedYear;
                    month = selectedMonth;
                    day   = selectedDay;

                    // Show selected date 
                     date2=""+day+"-"+month+"-"+year+" ";
                   Output2.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                            .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                            .append(" "));


                   }
                };
    }
```

//leavetask.java

```
package com.example.eleave;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URL;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class LeaveTask  extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    private Context context;
    public LeaveTask(Context context)
    {
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         try{
               String username=(String)arg0[0];
               String sem= (String)arg0[1];
               String reason=(String)arg0[2];
               String from=(String)arg0[3];
               String to=(String)arg0[4];
               String link = "http://trial.com/tl.php?username="
               +username+"&reason="+reason+"&from="+from+"&to="+to+"&sem="+sem;
               URL url = new URL(link);
               HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
               request.setURI(new URI(link));
               HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
               BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
              StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
              String line="";
              while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                 sb.append(line);
                 break;
               }
               in.close();
               return sb.toString();
         }catch(Exception e){
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
         }
    }
    protected void onPreExecute(){
       }
}
```

//tl.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("*****.com","*******","*******","********");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$username=$_GET['username'];
$reason=$_GET['reason'];
$from=$_GET['from'];
$to=$_GET['to'];
$sem=$_GET['sem'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT into test (phone_no,reason,from_date,to_date,sem) values('$username','$reason','$from','$to','$sem')");
echo $result;
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

//error
Exception:Illegal character in query at index 82://http://trial.com//tl.php?username=999999999&reason=ill&from=5-3-2014&to=6-3-14&sem=V

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your line

`$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT into test (phone_no,reason,from_date,to_date,sem) values('$username','$reason','$from','$to','$sem')");`

with

`$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT into test (phone_no,reason,from_date,to_date,sem) values('$username','$reason','$from','$to','$sem')") or die("MYSQLi Error::".mysqli_error($con));`